# pip is not able to install Cufflinks_ ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

Tags: python, installation, pip, cufflinks

I was trying to install cufflinks using pip. I am using this command " pip install cufflinks".

I am running command prompt as Administrator

After some time the installation fails and shows the below error.The error pops up after this line onwards.

**Getting requirements to build wheel ... error**

I tried many methods to solve this issue but failed. Can some please help me to solve this.

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\python27\python.exe' 'c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' get_requires_for_build_wheel 'c:\users\hoyyoth\appdata\local\temp\tmpyv0rcx'
       cwd: c:\users\hoyyoth\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-yixwp1\pywinpty
  Complete output (15 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
      main()
    File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 263, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 108, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      backend = _build_backend()
    File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 86, in _build_backend
      obj = import_module(mod_path)
    File "c:\python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
      __import__(name)
    File "c:\users\hoyyoth\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-env-wxu_ny\overlay\Lib\site-packages\maturin\__init__.py", line 31
      def get_config() -> Dict[str, str]:
                       ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python27\python.exe' 'c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' get_requires_for_build_wheel 'c:\users\hoyyoth\appdata\local\temp\tmpyv0rcx' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you're trying to install a Python 3.x -only library on Python 2. (The `->` syntax is Python 3 only.)

Upgrade to a Python 3 environment (3.9 is the newest version at the time of writing).

Comment: I installed latest version but still showing like as shown below.May I know how to update this C:\WINDOWS\system32>python --version
Python 2.7.14

C:\WINDOWS\system32>

Comment: How did you install it? Also, if you don't really need Python 2.7, you could uninstall it.

Comment: downloaded the exe file and installed it

Comment: Did you follow the instructions on adding it to your PATH?

Comment: Issue is solved after updating the environment variables